# Rails 4: Added name field to an existing user database but not validating correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have added a name field to an existing User database 
I validated the name field so it must be filled in. But when i run the app & add a name. I get **name cannot be blank** I have checked the database as well and the user's name is not added to the database. I have deleted the database again but get the same.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

         validates :name, presence: true

         has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy
end`
```

new_registrations.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>

    <div class="form-group">
      Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

listings.controller.rb

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /listings
  # GET /listings.json
  def index
    @listings = Listing.all
  end

  # GET /listings/1
  # GET /listings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /listings/new
  def new
    @listing = Listing.new
  end

  # GET /listings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /listings
  # POST /listings.json
  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
    @listing.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.update(listing_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /listings/1
  # DELETE /listings/1.json
  def destroy
    @listing.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to listings_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_listing
      @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:job, :description, :salary, :location)
    end
end
```

application.controller.rb

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
      # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
      protect_from_forgery with: :exception



      protected

      def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
         devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
      end
    end
```

rake routes

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                listings GET    /listings(.:format)            listings#index
                         POST   /listings(.:format)            listings#create
             new_listing GET    /listings/new(.:format)        listings#new
            edit_listing GET    /listings/:id/edit(.:format)   listings#edit
                 listing GET    /listings/:id(.:format)        listings#show
                         PATCH  /listings/:id(.:format)        listings#update
                         PUT    /listings/:id(.:format)        listings#update
                         DELETE /listings/:id(.:format)        listings#destroy
                   about GET    /about(.:format)               pages#about
                 contact GET    /contact(.:format)             pages#contact
                    root GET    /                              listings#index
```

Comment: Did you add the name field to your strong parameters?  Please share your controller code.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean Nice catch on the strong parameters.

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Comment: controller code as requested

Comment: i don't have a users controller

Comment: rake routes as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In application_controller put

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
...

end
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the comments, you seem to miss the before_action in your application_controller.

Comment: I changed the configure_permitted_parameters method, try it again

Comment: nope when i try to sign up I still get "Name can't be blank" -  "1 error prohibited this user from being saved"

Comment: In your ApplicationController you dont have the before_action that i posted in my example, it wont work without it.

Comment: It's not the content of the `configure_permitted_parameters` method that's the issue - as @Pierre says, you are not actually calling it because you don't have the `before_action...` line

Comment: yes working now my fault, thanks , so would i use the same line to edit the name field e.g. (:account_name).....